# Froala image align doesn't work

Tags: html, css, froala

I installed Froala successfully on my website, but positioning images doesn't seem to work.. They're always at the left, even if I align them center / right..

So in the Text-edit mode it works fine..

[image]

But after watching the result, all the 3 aligments look the same.

[image]

The images have these classes:

```
class="fr-dib fr-draggable fr-fil"  // this should be left align
class="fr-dib fr-draggable"  // this should be center align (doesn't work)
class="fr-dib fr-draggable fr-fir"  // and this should be right align (doesn't work)
```

I found a way to fix this, by making an own css with these lines:
(But honestly I think, there should be an another way)..

```
.fr-draggable {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
.fr-fil {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.fr-fir {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Could someone help me out?

**EDIT: My site looks like this:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>MySite</title>

        <!-- Style -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/css/custom.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/css/adminPOST.css" />

                <!-- FROALA CSS -->
                <link href="common/plugins/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <link href="common/plugins/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <link href="common/plugins/froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.3.0/codemirror.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="common/plugins/froala-editor/css/plugins/char_counter.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="common/plugins/froala-editor/css/plugins/code_view.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="common/plugins/froala-editor/css/plugins/colors.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="common/plugins/froala-editor/css/plugins/emoticons.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="common/plugins/froala-editor/css/plugins/file.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="common/plugins/froala-editor/css/plugins/fullscreen.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="common/plugins/froala-editor/css/plugins/image.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="common/plugins/froala-editor/css/plugins/image_manager.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="common/plugins/froala-editor/css/plugins/line_breaker.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="common/plugins/froala-editor/css/plugins/quick_insert.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="common/plugins/froala-editor/css/plugins/table.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="common/plugins/froala-editor/css/plugins/video.css">       
        <!-- JS -->
        <script src="common/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="common/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="common/js/jquery.elastic.source.js"></script>
        <script src="common/js/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/froala_editor.min.js"></script>
                <script src="common/js/adminPOST.js"></script>

                <!-- FROALA JS -->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/froala_editor.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.3.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.3.0/mode/xml/xml.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/align.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/char_counter.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/code_beautifier.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/code_view.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/colors.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/emoticons.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/entities.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/file.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/font_family.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/font_size.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/fullscreen.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/image.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/image_manager.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/inline_style.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/line_breaker.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/link.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/lists.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/paragraph_format.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/paragraph_style.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/quick_insert.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/quote.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/table.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/save.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/url.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/plugins/video.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="common/plugins/froala-editor/js/languages/hu.js"></script>      
    </head>
    <body>etc...</body></html>
```

**UPDATE:**

I found the Froala image styles in the css/froala_style.css (or in the min version):

```
/**
 * Image style.
 */
a.fr-view.fr-strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}
a.fr-view.fr-green {
  color: green;
}
/**
 * Link style.
 */
img.fr-view {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}
img.fr-view.fr-dib {
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
img.fr-view.fr-dib.fr-fil {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.fr-fir {
  margin-right: 0;
}
img.fr-view.fr-dii {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  max-width: calc(100% - (2 * 5px));
}
img.fr-view.fr-dii.fr-fil {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  max-width: calc(100% - 5px);
}
img.fr-view.fr-dii.fr-fir {
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 5px);
}
img.fr-view.fr-rounded {
  border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
img.fr-view.fr-bordered {
  border: solid 10px #CCC;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

But now what? Should I change something?:/

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share a link to your application or create a sample application which reproduces the problem you're seeing?

Answer (score 8):

UPDATE 2:

Problem solved.. had to write class="fr-view" to the div where I'm displaying the content. I'm so dumb.. sorry guys!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by, "... and any necessary namespace classes?"

Comment: Thank god HAHA. ChatGPT is too smart to give me this simple answer haha

Answer (score 2):

I think you just add this head

```
<!-- Include external CSS. -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.25.0/codemirror.min.css">

<!-- Include Editor style. -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.8.4/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.8.4/css/froala_style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- CSS rules for styling the element inside the editor such as p, h1, h2, etc. -->
<link href="../css/froala_style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- Include external JS libs. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.25.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.25.0/mode/xml/xml.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include Editor JS files. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.8.4/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize the editor. -->
<script> $(function() { $('textarea').froalaEditor() }); </script>
```

And your body tag

```
 <div class="fr-view">
  <!-- where you display your data -->
 </div>
```

Comment: Add some description

Comment: Adding "fr-view" class worked for me but I also had to include styles:
import 'froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css';
import 'froala-editor/css/froala_editor.min.css';

I am also using allowedTags method so in order to everything work properly correct tags need to be enabled as well. For example in my case adding image caption didn't work properly as I didn't allow span tags and found out this later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you're using Froala inside of a back-end CMS; have you also included Froala's stylesheet in your *application*'s stylesheet and any necessary namespace classes?

Comment: I edited my post.. I included all the Froala's stylesheet as you see:/

Comment: Does your code contain the necessary namespace classes? e.g. `img.fr-view.fr-dii`? [src](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/blob/7975753fd722b2358c6b64e3f25d9e24a13a3891/css/froala_style.css#L264-L272)

Comment: No, I don't see them. I've searched for them in all file (notepad++) In which file should it be? And maybe can you post the right css code for these missing styles? I downloaded froala from the offical site.. how is this possibble that this style is missing?

Comment: Those classes would need to exist on the image, as it appears in your markup.

Comment: Updated..:/ I don't understand what's happening

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was not including the `froala_style.min.css` file. Once I included that the aligning started to work.